# Why columns in slick Tables are defs instead of vals?

Tags: scala, slick

In [slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html) columns in table are defined with `def`

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales = column[Int]("SALES", O.Default(0))
  def total = column[Int]("TOTAL", O.Default(0))
  def * = (name, supID, price, sales, total)
}
```

Is there a reason why it shouldn't be like this:

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  val name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  val supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  val price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  val sales = column[Int]("SALES", O.Default(0))
  val total = column[Int]("TOTAL", O.Default(0))
  val * = (name, supID, price, sales, total)
}
```

It seems like columns don't use anything that could change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: 
initialization order.

**Long answer:**

Lets gather some facts:

1) using `val`s instead of `def`s mostly works (if you change most of `def`s to `val`s in your code it would most of the time behave correctly - at least this is how it works for me)

2) most examples of `Slick` code use `def`s.

So it may be that if something wrong happens it happens only in some (rare?) cases.

Some light may be shed by this part of code in `Slick` itself (take a look at comment after `if(tt == null)` (class `RelationalProfile):

```
def column[C](n: String, options: ColumnOption[C]*)(implicit tt: TypedType[C]): Rep[C] = {
      if(tt == null) throw new NullPointerException(
        "implicit TypedType[C] for column[C] is null. "+
        "This may be an initialization order problem. "+
        "When using a MappedColumnType, you may want to change it from a val to a lazy val or def.")
      new Rep.TypedRep[C] {
        override def toNode =
          Select((tableTag match {
            case r: RefTag => r.path
            case _ => tableNode
          }), FieldSymbol(n)(options, tt)) :@ tt
        override def toString = (tableTag match {
          case r: RefTag => "(" + _tableName + " " + r.path + ")"
          case _ => _tableName
        }) + "." + n
      }
    }
```

If you take a look at commit that introduced this change: https://github.com/slick/slick/commit/be2ff6513d46abc9a25c8752c2931a786d4c5ad6

you should find pretty good explanation (commit comments).